Why are consecutive 6s faster conditioning on no odd rolls?
Let A be the expected number of rolls of a fair d6 until you roll two consecutive sixes, conditional on every roll up to the consecutive sixes being even.
Let B be the expected number of rolls of a fair d6 until you roll two sixes, not necessarily consecutively, conditional on every roll up to the second six being even.
What is the most intuitively satisfying explanation for why B > A?
Source

Per a comment in the source, a key point is that "conditional on every prior roll being even" is a much more stringent condition for A than for B. Put differently, you're much more likely to roll an odd number at some point before rolling two sixes in a row than you are before rolling any two sixes, so A is heavily biased towards mostly shorter sequences being successful (though a much smaller proportion of overall sequences to be sure).

I found two things helpful.  First, simplify: there are only two outcomes to consider (2 or 4; 6).  Second, draw the finite-state automata corresponding to "A" and "B."  You can analyze them as described in our posts on Penney's Game.
